# Android. Error In Parse Query

Tags: android, parse-platform, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat application in that I am using Firebase to store and transfer message and Parse to store all the users data like(User sign up, login, storing recent table and sending push).

In Parse I stored all the user login data in Usertable, and I am maintaining one Recent table to store all the recent chat. 
User one to one chat will be saved under one GroupId(String). That group Id was formed by adding

```
GroupId = UserOneObjectId+UserTwoObjectId;
```

If someone made a new chat with particular person it will store the data about the recent chat in the Recent table, mainly it has to store the GroupId and members detail in array for exmp:

```
members = [UserOneObjectId, UserTwoObjectId]
```

for the next time if the user is making a chat again with the same person it has to query the table and look for the members array. if both person object id is already present it has to get that **GroupId** from that row.

for that I added these code. But this is not working kindly check and tell what mistake I am making...

And My full code is...

```
public class StartChat extends AppCompatActivity {

private String FIREBASE_URL = "https://craking-fire-base.cracked.com/";

private String user1ObjectId, user1Name;
private String user2ObjectId, user2Name;
private static String groupId;

private Firebase mFirebaseRef;
private Chat chat;
private ChatListAdapter mChatListAdapter;
private ValueEventListener mConnectedListener;
private PrefManager pref;
private Toolbar mtoolbar;

private ListView listView;
private EditText inputText;

String groupIdGot;

ParseObject entryToRecentChat;

ParseQuery<ParseObject> groupIdQuery;

public StartChat() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_chat);

    mtoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mtoolbar.setTitle(user2Name);

    pref = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());

    user1ObjectId = pref.getObjectId();
    user1Name = pref.getUserName();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    user2ObjectId = i.getStringExtra("user2ObjectId");
    user2Name = i.getStringExtra("user2Name");


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    /*groupId = user1ObjectId + user2ObjectId;*/

    groupIdQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Recent");
    groupIdQuery.whereContainsAll("members", Arrays.asList(user1ObjectId, user2ObjectId));
    Log.d("objectArray", Arrays.asList(user1ObjectId, user2ObjectId).toString());
    groupIdQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null)
            {
                for (ParseObject dealsObject : list) {
                    // use dealsObject.get('columnName') to access the properties of the Deals object.
                    String objId = dealsObject.getObjectId();
                    groupIdGot = (String) dealsObject.get("groupId");
                    Log.d("GroupId***Got", groupIdGot);
                    //String members = (String) dealsObject.get("members");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ObjectId: " + objId + "\n" + "GroupId: " + groupId + " value present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " No Data present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                groupId = user1ObjectId + user2ObjectId;

                entryToRecentChat = new ParseObject("Recent");
                entryToRecentChat.put("groupId", groupId);
                entryToRecentChat.put("lastUser", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", user1ObjectId));
                entryToRecentChat.put("user", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", user2ObjectId));
                entryToRecentChat.addAllUnique("members", Arrays.asList(user1ObjectId, user2ObjectId));
                entryToRecentChat.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value not saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    //groupId = user1ObjectId + user2ObjectId;
    if(groupIdGot != null){
        groupId = groupIdGot;
    }else{
        groupId = user1ObjectId + user2ObjectId;
    }

    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("Message").child(groupId);

    inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageInput);
    inputText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                sendMessage();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    //input = inputText.getText().toString();
    findViewById(R.id.sendButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendMessage();
            sendPush();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_start_chat, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Setup our view and list adapter. Ensure it scrolls to the bottom as data changes
    //final ListView listView = getListView();
    mtoolbar.setTitle(user2Name);
    mChatListAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(mFirebaseRef.limit(50), this, R.layout.chat_message, user1Name);
    listView.setAdapter(mChatListAdapter);
    mChatListAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            listView.setSelection(mChatListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });

    // Finally, a little indication of connection status
    mConnectedListener = mFirebaseRef.getRoot().child(".info/connected").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            boolean connected = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (connected) {
                Toast.makeText(StartChat.this, "Connected to ChatRoom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(StartChat.this, "Disconnected from ChatRoom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            // No-op
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mFirebaseRef.getRoot().child(".info/connected").removeEventListener(mConnectedListener);
    mChatListAdapter.cleanup();
}

private void sendMessage() {
    String input = inputText.getText().toString();
    if (!input.equals("")) {
        // Create our 'model', a Chat object
        chat = new Chat(input, user1Name);
        // Create a new, auto-generated child of that chat location, and save our chat data there
        mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(chat);
        inputText.setText("");
    }
}
```

Particularly I am getting nullpointer error in this line

```
 mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("Message").child(groupId);
```

Because for me this query is not working for me.

```
    groupIdQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Recent");
    groupIdQuery.whereContainsAll("members", Arrays.asList(user1ObjectId, user2ObjectId));
    Log.d("objectArray", Arrays.asList(user1ObjectId, user2ObjectId).toString());
    groupIdQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null)
            {
                for (ParseObject dealsObject : list) {
                    // use dealsObject.get('columnName') to access the properties of the Deals object.
                    String objId = dealsObject.getObjectId();
                    groupIdGot = (String) dealsObject.get("groupId");
                    Log.d("GroupId***Got", groupIdGot);
                    //String members = (String) dealsObject.get("members");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ObjectId: " + objId + "\n" + "GroupId: " + groupId + " value present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " No Data present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                groupId = user1ObjectId + user2ObjectId;

                entryToRecentChat = new ParseObject("Recent");
                entryToRecentChat.put("groupId", groupId);
                entryToRecentChat.put("lastUser", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", user1ObjectId));
                entryToRecentChat.put("user", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", user2ObjectId));
                entryToRecentChat.addAllUnique("members", Arrays.asList(user1ObjectId, user2ObjectId));
                entryToRecentChat.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value not saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    //groupId = user1ObjectId + user2ObjectId;
    if(groupIdGot != null){
        groupId = groupIdGot;
    }else{
        groupId = user1ObjectId + user2ObjectId;
    }
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a great medium for debugging your code. When you get a null pointer exception, put a breakpoint on the line that throws the exception and check each part of the statement. I've written some more info in an answer below. If that doesn't allow you to solve your problem, you'll have to reduce the code to the minimum needed to get your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you say:

> Particularly I am getting nullpointer error in this line

```
 mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("Message").child(groupId);
```

A `NullPointerException` is thrown when you try to call a method on a `null` value.

```
"SO".toString(); // works
null.toString(); // throws a NullPointerException
```

I always remember this as:

> a `NullPointerException` is thrown when you have a `null` value before a dot

There are two dots in your statement, so two places where `NullPointException` can be thrown. Let's split the statement over a few lines:

```
 mFirebaseRef = 
     new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL) // can this be null?
         .child("Message")      // can this be null?
         .child(groupId);
```

So either `new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL)` returns null, or `child("Messages")` returns null. Given how Firebase works, it is most likely that `child("Message")` returns null. So your database doesn't had a child node called `Message`.

Comment: I solved the issue. Its because of .child("Message"). Actually the structure in url and the firebase list adapter class is different... So I got that error. Now everything is fine. Thank you.

Comment: How to add a left and ight alignment in firebase chat? can u tell me how to do it?